# command uses visibleWhen not appear in context menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I wanna add a context menu command when select `Java Source Files`, but the context menu don't appear.
The class type of `Java Source Files` is `CompilationUnit` which i get from `eclipse plugin-in spy`.

This is plugin extension declaration(**plugin.xml**):

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="xml2javacode.commands.sampleCommand"
               id="xml2javacode.menus.sampleCommand"
               mnemonic="S">
            <visibleWhen>
               <with
                     variable="activeMenuSelection">
                  <iterate>
                     <instanceof
                           value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit">
                     </instanceof>
                  </iterate>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several classes called `CompilationUnit` and you have chosen the wrong one.

```xml
 <instanceof
     value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit">
 </instanceof>
```

works - **but** this is an internal class so you should not reference it.

The usual way to check for a Java source file is:

```xml
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.contentTypeId" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource" />
</adapt>
```

which is adapting the selection to an `IResource` and then checking the content type id.

Comment: Excellent! Thank u very much, it succeed, i just use `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit`,                                             it may cause `permGen out of memory`,                                                 using `IResource` doesn't have this problem.